# How to control mouse movement and be able to move the ILNumerics ILColorbar at the same time

Tags: ilnumerics

The ILColorBar has a property called Movable.  If set to false you can't move the colorbar on the surface.  If set to true and you have written custom events for the mouse movement (MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseLeave, MouseMove) these don't fire.  But they do fire if Moveable is set to false.

I want to be able to move the colorbar if your mouse is hovering over the left 50% of the width of the colorbar and have the mouse interact with the colorbar if it is hovering over the right 50% of the colorbar.

Do I leave Moveable to false and manually move the colorbar based on mousedown and mousemove events and state?  Or do I toggle the Moveable property?  Or is there a better way or is this even possible?